# Question concerning a sequence in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, combinations, gap

I would like to know, what's the best (fastest) way to programm the following in GAP (perhaps using some functionality from the [QPA package](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~oyvinso/QPA/)):

Input:

$n\geq 2$

Output:

A list of all sequences ${(c_i)}_{i=0}^{n-1}$ with the following properties:

$\bullet$ $2\leq \min \{c_i\ |\ i=0,...,n-1\}=c_0 \leq n+1$

$\bullet$ $c_{n-1}=c_0+1$

$\bullet$ $c_{i-1}-1\leq c_i$ for $i=1,...,n-1$

Example:
The case $n=3$ should give the following result:

$[[2,2,3],[2,3,3],[2,4,3],[3,3,4],[3,4,4],[3,5,4],[4,4,5],[4,5,5],[4,6,5]]$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: GAP indexes list elements starting from 1. Can we modify the question to index sequences starting from 1, not from 0?

Comment: Perhaps one should iterate over the 1st element of the tuple. Then the last element of the tuple is just the first plus 1. it remains to find all tuples of elements to insert between them, satisfying given constraints.

Comment: I've also reformulated the question. GAP provides the runtime-environment and the programming language, and QPA is a package, not yet redistributed with GAP and known only to experts, so the link will make finding it easier). You program in GAP, not in QPA, but of course you can use functionality which QPA provides...

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and for editing my question. Yes, I think that it doesn't matter, when we start with $c_1$, as long as the output is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but I couldn't render this properly in mathjax, but copy-past will work. I hope this gives the result.

```
fun:=function(n)
local c0,cn_1,T,t,s,ret;
ret:=[];
for c0 in [2..n+1] do 
    cn_1:=c0+1;
    T:=Tuples([c0..cn_1+1],n-2);
    for t in T do 
        s:=Concatenation([c0],t,[cn_1]);
        if ForAll([2..n],i->s[i-1]-1<=s[i]) then 
            Add(ret,s); 
        fi;
    od;
od;
return ret;
end;
```

**Update**: this is a little bit more fine-tuned version of the function above. First, I've switched to `IteratorOfTuples` to avoid filling up the memory with tuples and then throwing some of them away when the condition checked by `ForAll` fails. Second, a very important observation is to not use `Concatenation` with multiple lists. In

```
s:=Concatenation([c0],t,[cn_1]);
```

first a new list `l` is created to concatenate the 1st two arguments, and then another new list will be created to copy over the list `l` and then `[cn_1]`. I've reduced at least one copying of the list `t` by concatenating the first two lists and then adding the last element to the result.

```
fun2:=function(n)
local c0,c,cn_1,T,t,s,ret;
ret:=[];
for c0 in [2..n+1] do 
    c := [c0];
    cn_1:=c0+1;
    T:=IteratorOfTuples([c0..cn_1+1],n-2);
    for t in T do 
        s:=Concatenation( c, t );
        s[n]:=cn_1;
        if ForAll([2..n],i->s[i-1]-1<=s[i]) then 
            Add(ret,s);
        fi;
    od;
od;
return ret;
end;
```

It now produces the result for $n=15$ a little bit faster:

```
gap> fun(15);;time;
104102
gap> fun2(15);;time;      
89032
```

Also, it does not run out of memory immediately for $n=20$ but I am not enough patient to wait till it enumerates just 387420489 tuples of length 18 from [2..4] even on the first iteration :-)

So, for $n=20$ this already looks impractical. I may have some further ideas to suggest:

- There are many tuples which are generated and then thrown away because the condition `ForAll([2..n],i->s[i-1]-1<=s[i])` fails. One may try to write an own function to generate all tuples satisfying such restriction instead of using `Tuples` or `IteratorOfTuples`. Maybe this will be faster, but beware that already for $n=15$ we have $4767165$ tuples in the result.
- The condition always fails "in the middle", so it is the tuple `t` which either satisfies it or not. Hence, we may select "good tuples" of length $n-2$ for `[1..3]` once, and then use that to construct all good tuples of length $n-2$ for `[c0..c0+2]`. This will not help with $n=20$ since one still to pass through the first iteration, but may speed up smaller cases.

**Update 2**: I've implemented my suggestion about selecting "good" tuples first. Note the following piece of GAP syntax:

```
gap> r:=[11..13];
[ 11 .. 13 ]
gap> t:=[1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,1];
[ 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1 ]
gap> r{t};       
[ 11, 12, 13, 12, 11, 13, 12, 11, 11 ]
```

So, the third version of the function is

```
fun3:=function(n)
local c0,c,cn_1,T,t,s,good,range,ret;
ret:=[];
good:=[];
T:=IteratorOfTuples([1..3],n-2);
# selecting patterns of "good" tuples
for s in T do
    if ForAll([2..n-2],i->s[i-1]-1<=s[i]) then 
        Add(good,s);
    fi;
od;
# creating tuples from patterns 
for c0 in [2..n+1] do 
    c := [c0];
    cn_1:=c0+1;
    range := [c0..cn_1+1];
    for t in good do 
        s:=Concatenation( c, range{t} );
        s[n]:=cn_1;
        Add(ret,s);
    od;
od;
return ret;
end;
```

This version is more than 7 times faster for $n=15$:

```
gap> fun(15);;time;         
104176
gap> fun3(15);;time;
14318
```

It took 40 seconds for $n=16$, but choke on $n=17$. Anyhow, perhaps you may modify our code and process the resulting tuples as soon as they are generated instead of storing them, so hope this is of some help. Would be interesting to know what are the values of $n$ for which you're interested to calculate this in practice.

Comment: Thanks. If you use four spaces to indent the code, it is displayed nicely. I really miss GitHub's markup here when you can just mark the beginning and end of the code block, instead of indenting each line :-(

Comment: Thanks. And now for n=15 it takes a while and produces list of 4767165 tuples. For n=20 it runs out of memory at some call of `Tuples`. I suggest to switch to using `IteratorOfTuples` instead of `Tuples` ans check tuples one by one. This will not fill up the memory with the list of tuples before filtering them.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov in the original g-code in GAP I used 4 spaces because I like it for myself for clarity, but when I copy-pasted it it gave the result I had. Moreover I tried \begin{verbatim} (as in TXC) but to no avail. Is there any MathJax code involved?

Comment: No MathJax here. Please have a look at [my edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/936370/revisions). You've used indentation to indent loops, not for the whole chunk of the GAP code.

Comment: Pffff! Where could I have found this trick? Clearly not in the mathjax reference. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: When writing an answer, there is a question mark on the top of the input window. Clicking on it, you will find basic help and a link to more detailed [Editing Help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov your remarks are extremely useful not only in this particular situation but also in other ones I'll be publishing soon. I didn't know the OP was going into big numbers but I'm glad GAP provides such nice solutions!